# How to fix NPM UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY :npm ERR! peer dep missing: bufferutil@^4.0.1, required by ws@7.2.1

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project git clone from GitLab with local using( Ubuntu, Node.js @v9), but found that problem:
(npm ERR! peer dep missing: bufferutil@^4.0.1, required by ws@7.2.1 ) but I commanded "npm list", found 
that ws@7.2.1 is already installed in the node_moudules.how to fix??

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules` and reinstalling it again with  `npm install`?

Comment: I think you're using an old nodejs version. Try to update it to at least node v10. The easy way to update node can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-update-node-js-and-npm-to-next-version/ After update node, delete node_modules and run: npm i

Answer (score 0):

npm install bufferutil --save-optional